# Preparing to unpack /var/lib/dpkg/info/software-properties-gtk.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/software-properties-gtk.prerm: py3clean: not found

Tags: 14.04, python

I removed python from /usr/bin/

```
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Preparing to unpack .../python3-problem-report_2.20.1-0ubuntu2.9_all.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-problem-report.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-problem-report.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-problem-report_2.20.1-0ubuntu2.9_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-problem-report.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-problem-report.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Preparing to unpack .../python3-apport_2.20.1-0ubuntu2.9_all.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-apport.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-apport.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-apport_2.20.1-0ubuntu2.9_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-apport.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-apport.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Preparing to unpack .../software-properties-common_0.96.20.7_all.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/software-properties-common.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/software-properties-common.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/software-properties-common_0.96.20.7_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              /var/lib/dpkg/info/software-properties-common.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/software-properties-common.postinst: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Preparing to unpack .../software-properties-gtk_0.96.20.7_all.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/software-properties-gtk.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/software-properties-gtk.prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/software-properties-gtk_0.96.20.7_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              /var/lib/dpkg/info/software-properties-gtk.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/software-properties-gtk.postinst: py3compile: not found
```

Comment: Do you still have binaries `/usr/bin/python2.7` and `/usr/bin/python3.4`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 16.04 Completely broken python3 + dpkg + apt-get!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1092919/ubuntu-16-04-completely-broken-python3-dpkg-apt-get)

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command:

```
apt-get  -f install
```

to correct a system with broken dependencies in place.

Try also: `dpkg --configure -a`.

---

Note that `py3compile` file is part of `python3-minimal` package, so if you still got the problem, try reinstalling that package. If you can't reinstall using `apt-get`, try to [download `.pkg` file from kernel.org](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3-defaults/) and install manually (python3-minimal*). E.g.

```
dpkg -i python3-minimal_*.deb
```